# Demonstration site CDF error correction question

Tags: manipulate, code-review, demonstrations

I use Mathematica ver11.

However, the following error is displayed when running Demonstration site.

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ThreeOrthogonalProjectionsOfPolyhedra/

```
px[r_] := {0, r[[2]], r[[3]]}; 
py[r_] := {r[[1]], 0, r[[3]]};
pz[r_] := {r[[1]], r[[2]], 0};
pxs[solid_] := {solid[[1]], Map[px, solid[[2]]], solid[[3]]};
pys[solid_] := {solid[[1]], Map[py, solid[[2]]], solid[[3]]};
pzs[solid_] := {solid[[1]], Map[pz, solid[[2]]], solid[[3]]};
show[poly_][solid_] := Map[poly, Map[solid[[2, #]] &, solid[[1]]]];
trans[vec_][r_] := r + vec
translate3[vec_, solid_] := {solid[[1]], Map[trans[vec], solid[[2]]],solid[[3]]};
translate23[vec_][solid_] := translate3[vec, solid];
ClosedLine[a_] := Line[Append[a, First[a]]];
visible[solid_, view_][edge_] := Module[{edges = solid[[3]], vert = solid[[2]], faces = solid[[1]], f = Length[solid[[1]]], fac, normals}, fac = Select[Range[f], Length[Intersection[faces[[#]], edge]] == 2 &];
normals = Table[Normalize[
 Cross[vert[[faces[[fac[[i]], 2]]]] - vert[[faces[[fac[[i]], 1]]]], 
  vert[[faces[[fac[[i]], 3]]]] - vert[[faces[[fac[[i]], 1]]]]]], {i, 1, 2}]; view.normals[[1]] > 0.001 || view.normals[[2]] > 0.001 ]
visib2[solid_, viewp_, prsolid_] :=  Table[{If[! visible[solid, viewp][solid[[3, j]]], Dashed, Thin], Line[Map[prsolid[[2, #]] &, prsolid[[3, j]]]]}, {j, 1, Length[solid[[3]]]}];  


Manipulate[ Module[{cc, cc1, py1, pyss},   cc1 = With[{cu = PolyhedronData[p, "Faces"], 
 cu1 = PolyhedronData[p, "Edges"]}, {cu[[2, 1]], cu[[1]] // N, 
 cu1[[2, 1]]}]; cc = translate23[{xx, yy, zz}][cc1]; 
 pyss = pys[cc]; py1 = visib2[cc, {0, 100, 0}, pyss]; 
Column[{Graphics3D[{{GrayLevel[0.6], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {5 + xx, 0, 0}, {5 + xx, 0, 5 + zz}, {0, 0, 
      5 + zz}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, {GrayLevel[0.6], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, yy + 5, 0}, {0, yy + 5, 5 + zz}, {0, 0, 
      5 + zz}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, {GrayLevel[0.6], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {5 + xx, 0, 0}, {5 + xx, 5 + yy, 0}, {0, 
      5 + yy, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, visib2[cc, {0, 0, 100}, pzs[cc]], 
  visib2[cc, {0, 100, 0}, pys[cc]], 
  visib2[cc, {100, 0, 0}, pxs[cc]], 
  If[shs, show[If[ef == 1, Polygon, ClosedLine]][cc], {}]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {3, 3, 1}, ViewAngle -> 15 Degree, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 SphericalRegion -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-.5, 4.7}, {-.5, 4.7}, {-2, 4.7}}]}]], {{p,"SquashedDodecahedron", "polyhedron"},Intersection[PolyhedronData["Convex"], PolyhedronData[;; 14]]}, Row[{"translate   ", Column[{
 Control@{{xx, 2, Style["x", Italic]}, 1, 3, .001, 
   ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Control@{{yy, 2, Style["y", Italic]}, 1, 3, .001, 
   ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Control@{{zz, 2, Style["z", Italic]}, 1, 3, .001,  ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}  }], Spacer[20],   Control@{{shs, True, "show solid"}, {True, False}}, Spacer[20],   Control@{{ef, 1, ""}, {1 -> "polygon", 2 -> "line"}, Enabled -> shs}   }], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

However, I want to know why an error occurs.

Comment: Execute `PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"]` and `PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces", "Polygon"]` and see if you think they should be interchangeable.

Comment: @MichaelE2 the syntax in V11 has changed. in V10.4 `PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"]` returns `GraphicsComplex`. I noticed it earlier but didn't have time to investigate all details, maybe it is good place to ask about all changes in `PolyhedronData`? Giving as example `PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"]` instead of op's code. What do you think?

Comment: @Kuba Yeah, kinda funny they break their own code, in a sense. -- Your interpretation of the Q seems reasonable, and if so, I misinterpreted what was meant in the original Original Post.

Comment: Thanks to a friendly explanation, I solved it well.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax for `PolyhedronData` was changed in v11 you need to replace this line:

```
cc1 = With[
    { cu = PolyhedronData[p, "Faces"]
    , cu1 = PolyhedronData[p, "Edges"]
    }
  , { cu[[2, 1]]
    , cu[[1]] // N
    , cu1[[2, 1]]
    }
];
```

with:

```
cc1 = With[
    { cu = PolyhedronData[p, "GraphicsComplex"]
    , cu1 = PolyhedronData[p, "Edges"]
    }
  , { cu[[2, 1]]
    , cu[[1]] // N
    , cu1
    }
];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to a friendly explanation, I solved it well.