# What has changed in PolyhedronData in V11

Tags: geometry, curated-data, compatibility, polyhedra

As we saw in:

[Demonstration site CDF error correction question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146730/5478)

`PolyhedronData` has changed. I've failed to find any information about how the syntax changed in V11.

Example:

```
PolyhedronData["SquashedDodecahedron", "Faces"]
```

> V10.4:
>
> GraphicsComplex[...]
>
> V11.1.1:
>
> {{1, 4, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 11, 8}, {3, 8, 2, 1}, {10, 13, 7, 5}, {12, 14, 
>     13, 10}, {5, 6, 12, 10}, {7, 13, 9, 4}, {13, 14, 11, 9}, {14, 12, 8,
>      11}, {12, 6, 2, 8}, {6, 5, 1, 2}, {5, 7, 4, 1}}

In 11.1 we can get the 'old' faces with:

```
PolyhedronData["SquashedDodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]
```

But it is not the case with e.g. "Edges" so the transition is not straightforward.

**The question**: I was able to fix this example but in general I'd like to have an outline of changes and/or quick `v11Patch` would be nice, in order to don't have to think when transferring older code to v11.

Comment: Makes you wish [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html) was still maintained.

Comment: @JasonB. Maybe this deserves an entry [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56728/incompatible-changes-since-mathematica-version-7)

Answer (score 3):

It is [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyhedronData.html) that the `"Edges"` property returns the polyhedron edges **as vertex index pairs** (emphasis mine).

It is also documented that one might use

```
PolyhedronData["SquashedDodecahedron", "Edges", "GraphicsComplex"]
```

to get the previous form.

Another useful feature of the documentation page is the "UPDATED (show changes)" button -- try clicking on that and reading the highlighted sections of the page.

[image]

Comment: I know that feature, it is quite common due to the symbolic `File` wrapper introduction. And this subtle change is stressed out with the same magnitude as backward incompatible change in syntax for quite important function. I don't claim the current syntax is not clear, new documentation looks well. I just think it fails to communicate how severe was the update. That is of course subjective too.

Comment: Yes, quite a few functions were modified in 11.0 or later: `EntityList[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "VersionLastModified" -> GreaterEqualThan[11]]]` and I agree it would be nice to have a way to distinguish "simple" extensions from more major changes, especially ones that may introduce an incompatibility with existing code.