# Polyhedra disappear in stl export

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

I've created a `Graphics3D` object from Polyhedra and Cylinders to display a graph in the following way:

```
r = 0.08
t=0.032
Graphics3D[{
Scale[Translate[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron","Faces"],{ 2.66750601, -22.53764545, 0.00000000 }],r],
Scale[Translate[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron","Faces"],{ 3.47457065, -23.05227013, -0.58280430 }],r],
//a lot more of them
Cylinder[{{18.50108958, 10.99138316, -3.45322920}, {18.93607018, 12.04701963, -2.99792280}}, t],
Cylinder[{{18.93607018, 12.04701963, -2.99792280}, {18.73523370, 12.79058000, -2.01572440}}, t],
Cylinder[{{18.73523370, 12.79058000, -2.01572440}, {18.93637344, 14.32517816, -1.11278200}}, t],
//a lot more of them
}]
Export["spiral.stl", %]
```

When I display the `stl` file, I can see the cylinders but not the polyhedra.
It works if I replace the polyhedra with spheres, however.

What is the correct way to export those polyhedra to `stl`?

Comment: You want `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]`

Comment: @m_goldberg, "You want `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]`" - Mathematica tells me: `PolyhedronData has no value associated with the specified argument(s)`. I'm using version 10.4.10

Comment: About changes see: [What has changed in PolyhedronData in V11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146769/5478)

Comment: Your link suggests what I did in the first place, i.e. using the "Faces" property.